# Trying to resize a div to match the width of another div when clicked

Tags: jquery, grid, draggable, placeholder, sortables

So here's what I'm working on for reference:

http://www.ryanhammond.us/ellenpaul/index.html

If you look at the website, you'll see a grid of thumbnails. I used Jquery sortables to allow the thumbnails to be reordered.

All the thumbs are li's in an unordered list which the sortables function is applied to

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "ul" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "highlight"
    });
    $( "ul" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

My issue is that you specify only one placeholder for all the thumbnails (the placeholder is the light blue square that appears when you drag a thumb - it is .highlight) and I have two different thumbnail widths.     Sooooo if I set .highlight to width 300px it looks great with the 300px width thumbnails, but wrong with the thinner 200px thumbnails.

My best idea so far has been to write up another javascript code that detects the width of a thumbnail when it's clicked and resize the placeholder to that width...  but I'm new with java so I'm not sure if this is the best fix.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: java != javascript. And this is pretty easy with jQuery. look up `.click`, `.css` and `.width` in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Would basically go something along the lines of drop.width(selection.width())

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you are dragging the Div there is a class "ui-sortable-helper" added on it, so if you pick the width of the div once dragged, then resize all  divs having the class "highlight", it should work bellow is a sample :

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "ul" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "highlight",
      start: function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout("resize()",0);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    }
    });
    $( "ul" ).disableSelection();   
  });
function resize()
{
var width = $($(".ui-sortable-helper")[0]).css("width");
$($(".highlight")[0]).attr("style","width:"+width);
}
  </script>
```

Comment: Wow, yeah that worked perfectly - thank you so much! I'll have to study it for a while to see how it's working.